# What happens when enabling different "spatializing audio" sofware at the same time?

Tags: windows, audio, gaming, headphones, audio-conversion

For example: If I enable spatial audio from windows settings:
[image: windows Settings],
from logitech(gaming headphones company) ghub application:
[image: logitech ghub surround system settings]
and dolby atmos in the game(overwatcH):
[image: overwatch sound settings]
what will happen with the audio? will it decrease its quality? or softwares are smart enough they will use only one software for the spatial audio effect?

Answer (score 2):

A general answer is not really possible here.
It all depends on what the program is doing:

- If the program processes the video and then sends the result via Windows
  to the audio device, Windows will do its own processing in addition to
  the processing by the program.
- The program might also specify in its calls to Windows API other effects
  that will replace the ones specified by the user, or even specify no
  efects.
- If the program somehow integrates its processing into Windows,
  as by installing a DLL, its processing might win over that specified
  by the user.

There are many combinations possible for the architecture of the game
program, and many parameters values and combinations that it can specify
in its API calls. By observing what happens, one may have a guess as to
which of the possibilities are true for one specific game program.